# How to query a django model using another model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm new to django (and python) and I have a question.
I have this model:

```
class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and

```
class Experiments(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    experiment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to query it so I have only have the Materials used in the Experiments model. I was reading about Q objects but I'm not sure how to use it. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Some questions first: why is your `Material` model abstract? Do you really need a specific `throught` model for your `ManyToManyField`? In such a case, can you post this model as well?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I checked with my colleague and we changed the model. Is it better now?

Comment: Not really. What are you trying to represent? I believe that what you want is that an `Experiment` has (possibly) many `Material`. And that a `Material` (let's say `m`) can be part of many `Experiment` as well. Right? In such a case using a `ManyToManyField` was right. What I questioned was the need for specifying the `through` parameter. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) you will see that this is not mandatory. In order to help you better you should post all the models involved.

Comment: Can't really suggest anything if we don't know the relationship between the two models. Is it supposed to be a many-to-many relationship?